# Fatal error: Call to undefined function random_bytes()

Tags: php

I'm using php 5.6.23-0+deb8u1 and in my code I want use the function `random_bytes` but I get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function random_bytes()

I want to know if I need to import something or isn't included in this version of php, in this case, how can I replace it?

Comment: *Note:* Although this function was added to PHP in PHP 7.0, a » userland implementation is available for PHP 5.2 to 5.6, inclusive. Read the manual man

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[random_bytes()](https://secure.php.net/random_bytes) was introduced with PHP 7.

As stated in the manual:

> **Note:** Although this function was added to PHP in PHP 7.0, a [» userland implementation](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat) is available for PHP 5.2 to 5.6, inclusive.

You can use that userland implementation as a backport: https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat

Comment: there is nothing in php? I want avoid external libs

Comment: Anything available in PHP won't behave in the same way and can fail depending on the environment. I can personally guarantee that this library is the best solution out there. It has options to install it manually and treat it as local code - do that if you don't want to track third-party dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

`random_bytes` was introduced with PHP7 ([reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php)).

Alternatively for PHP versions below `7.0` like `5.6`, `5.5` etc, you can use custom function to generate random number using function below.

```
if( !function_exists('random_bytes') )
{
    function random_bytes($length = 6)
    {
        $characters = '0123456789';
        $characters_length = strlen($characters);
        $output = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
            $output .= $characters[rand(0, $characters_length - 1)];

        return $output;
    }
}
```

Comment: `mt_rand()` is NOT random, despite what its name implies, and not suitable for anything security-sensitive. That's pretty much the entire reason why `random_bytes()` was created.

Comment: My previous comment explains the downvote - suggesting `mt_rand()` is bad. And no, `rand()` is not random either ... you're adding more and more bad advice.

Comment: No. You don't get it ... `rand()` and `mt_rand()` are simply not random; they're seeded and predictable. Anything that you make that depends on them will not be random and not a viable alternative to `random_bytes()`. The updated answer is even worse now, because that function has numeric output.

Comment: Also, when you delete your comments you make it look like I'm talking to myself.